# Is there any reasonable way to get the (public) certificate from a TLS client without also decrypting the stream in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, ssl-certificate

The situation is this one: a *client* authenticates to a *server* using a signed certificate. Then a complete handshake is performed and the data are exchanged in a secure manner.

But depending on a number of elements, I need to associate each user to a specific server (many users can share the same server). The context can change in any instant and I want to be able to change this `user -> server` map without having to access the user device.

The most straightforward way seems to be the implementation of a **gateway/router** which uses the information from the client certificate to handle the routing.

The problem with that is that I have no idea of how to make such a router **without resorting to MITMing** (which I don't want for computational, security and privacy reasons): AFAIK, the `ssl` lib and `openssl` bindings in Python (which are fast, reliable and widespread) only provide wrapped sockets which handle the decryption part. There seems to be no public interface just to extract the certificate and forward the pristine stream to a suitable backend server.

**Do you know any way to get that certificate and forward the complete, unaltered, stream to another server without resorting to complicated schemes/workarounds?**